# Symfony in memory admin user with email authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, in-memory

I am authenticating my app with a class that extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator. The login form has email and password fields. I need to have a hardcoded user in memory and be able to log in through that log in form. How could i configure the security file to make that work?

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator

private $userRepository;
private $router;
private $passwordEncoder;

public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;

}

public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'app_login'
        && $request->isMethod('POST');
}

public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('login_form')['email'],
        'password' => $request->request->get('login_form')['plainPassword'],
    ];

    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['email']
    );

    return $credentials;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);

}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    //Redirects to homepage after login
    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_homepage'));
}

protected function getLoginUrl()
{
    return $this->router->generate('app_login');
}
```

In security.yml file under providers i have

```
in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin@admin.lt:
                    field: email
                    password: $2y$13$st6a8CcDt/X2ng.8b2brEeP0C/MiXSr78er4lTlnWIKzcCJv2ZF8y
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Authenticator asks for a UserRepository. You might have a custom repository that interacts with the InMemoryUserProvider, but what I would recommend is when you get the User in your authenticator to use the UserProviderInterface that is passed as well. Depending on which provider is configured both in the providers section as well as the one you picked in your firewall, this will be used. When you only have 1 UserProvider (your in_memory-provider) that will automatically be used in your firewall.

In your security.yaml you will not need to specify `field: email` as the form field is mapped to the username by your authenticator and the InMemoryUserProvider does not use this configuration in any way. This means for example your `getUser()` could look like this:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['email']);
}
```

The rest of your authenticator looks good to work with this as well. You will have to be careful in your application as the User-class you get back from the provider is not an Entity, but the default User-class provided by Symfony itself `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`.

Your providers section in `security.yaml` should probably look like in the docs (each user contains only `password` and `roles`) and in your firewall you might want to reference the provider using `provider: 'in_memory'` (or whatever other name you chose for the provider).